# Question regarding TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, math-operators

I've tried to create a figure using TikZ (see code below):

```
\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[SIR/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, fill=black!5, very thick, minimum size=8mm},  
]

%Nodes
\node[SIR]    (reverse)                              {$\Delta(C(X))$};
\node[SIR]    (topo-space)       [below=of reverse] {$X$};
\node[SIR]    (algebra)       [left=of topo-space] {$C(X)$};
\node[SIR]    (reverse2)       [right=of reverse] {$C(\Delta(\mathcal{A}))$};
\node[SIR]    (algebra2)       [below=of reverse2] {$\mathcal{A}$};
\node[SIR]    (structure-space)       [right=of algebra2] {$\Delta(\mathcal{A})$};

%Lines
\draw[->, dashed] (reverse.south)  to node[right]{$\ref{GNT-lemma}$} (topo-space.north);
\draw[->, very thick] (topo-space.west)  to node[below] {...} (algebra.east);
\draw[->, very thick] (algebra.north)  ..  controls  +(left:2mm) and +(left:7mm)   ..  (reverse.west);

\draw[->, very thick] (algebra2.east)  to node[below] {\ref{structure-lemma}} (structure-space.west);
\draw[->, dashed] (reverse2.south)  to node[right] {$b$} (algebra2.north);
\draw[->, very thick] (structure-space.north) .. controls  +(right:2mm) and +(right:7mm)   ..  (reverse2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

I´d like to write statements over the curved arrows, but it does not work using "to node[below] {...}". Besides I´d like to replace the dashed arrows with "isometric" symbols (something like $\cong$). How can I do that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: You might want to take a look into the [tag:tikz-cd] package/library. It uses a TikZ matrix to place nodes and directed `\arrow` macro to place the arrows. Re Replacing a line with a symbol, the easiest would be to not draw the path but just place a `sloped` node with `$\cong$` on top. Drawing the arrow as a `\cong` will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: You could replace `.. controls +(right:2mm) and +(right:7mm) ..` by `to[out=90, in=0]` and get the same syntax as with the other `to`-paths.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it.

[image: result]

#### Changes made:

I introduced two more styles for your drawn arrows to simplify the code a little.

References don't work, of course.

For the labels I introduced extra nodes, one with shift in polar coordinates, one shifting in cartesian coordinates AND sloped text, one simply with [left]; colors are for better indication.

Polar: 145 deg, 1cm radius, i.e. into the north-west

```
    \draw[arv,blue] (algebra.north)  to[out=90, in=180] % adopting Jaspers approach
                 node[shift=(145:1cm)] {something}      % putting a label, polar coordinates
                 (reverse.west);
```

Cartesian:

```
    \draw[arv,red] (structure-space.north) to [out=90,in=0] % Jaspers idea again
                    node[sloped,xshift=3mm,yshift=3mm] {hi} % sloped, cartesian shifts
                    (reverse2.east);
```

Left: not sure, if this is even close to what you wanted

```
    \draw[ard] (reverse.south)  to node[right]{$\ref{GNT-lemma}$}
    % >>> varied:
                                node[left,blue] {$\cong$} % did you mean that?
                                (topo-space.north);
```

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    SIR/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, fill=black!5, very thick, minimum size=8mm},
    % ~~~ some style-refactoring: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ard/.style={->, dashed},
    arv/.style={->, very thick},
    ]
    % ~~~ Nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[SIR] (reverse)                            {$\Delta(C(X))$};
    \node[SIR] (topo-space) [below=of reverse]      {$X$};
    \node[SIR] (algebra)    [left=of topo-space]    {$C(X)$};
    \node[SIR] (reverse2)   [right=of reverse]      {$C(\Delta(\mathcal{A}))$};
    \node[SIR] (algebra2)   [below=of reverse2]     {$\mathcal{A}$};
    \node[SIR] (structure-space) [right=of algebra2] {$\Delta(\mathcal{A})$};
    
    % ~~~ Lines // references don't work, of course ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[ard] (reverse.south)  to node[right]{$\ref{GNT-lemma}$}
    % >>> varied:
                                node[left,blue] {$\cong$} % did you mean that?
                                (topo-space.north);
    \draw[arv] (topo-space.west)  to node[below] {...} (algebra.east);
    % >>> varied: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[arv,blue] (algebra.north)  to[out=90, in=180] % adopting Jaspers approach
                 node[shift=(145:1cm)] {something}      % putting a label, polar coordinates
                 (reverse.west);
    
    \draw[arv] (algebra2.east)  to node[below] {\ref{structure-lemma}} (structure-space.west);
    \draw[ard] (reverse2.south)  to node[right] {$b$} (algebra2.north);
    % >>> varied: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[arv,red] (structure-space.north) to [out=90,in=0] % Jaspers idea again
                    node[sloped,xshift=3mm,yshift=3mm] {hi} % sloped, cartesian shifts
                    (reverse2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```